# Installing SQLite 3.6 On Windows 7

Tags: sqlite, windows-7

How do I install [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) 3.6 on Windows 7?

I extracted sqlite3.exe, sqlite3.dll, and sqlite3.def to C:\Windows\System32 but when I try to run a Ruby program that requires the use of sqlite3, I get this error:

> The program can't start because sqlite3.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

Comment: Does it work if you install all files (the calling application and the sqlite files) into single, ordinary folder?

Comment: It works if I add the files to the folder that has the ruby application in it, but the problem is that I have multiple applications that require the use of sqlite.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I would try adding the path to SQLite in PATH.

Supplemental: SQLite 3 is not "installed". It's a DLL, usually unregistered. Most software using SQLite 3 will rely on a local copy or one referenced in an environment variable.

Answer (score 13):

Just tried this on Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit. Didn't like it when I put it in the ruby/bin folder. Didn't like the \Winodws\System32 either... put it in the \Windows\system and it ran... go figure... anyway fyi for 64bit.

Comment: Same OS, your solution worked, thanks for posting.  Weird that it doesn't work in System32...

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 64 bit here as well, putting them in \Windows\system did it for me.

Actually I was installing this for HDBC and Haskell following the instructions at http://wiki.github.com/jgoerzen/hdbc/frequentlyaskedquestions

The only difference for Windows 7 64 bit is in the below instruction -

"Put “sqlite3.dll” from sqlitedll-3*.zip into ghc --print-libdir and into %windir%\system32."

The file should be copied into the \Windows\system instead of the %windir%\system32 folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when trying to run Rake (bundle exec rake db:migrate).

I tried setting the PATH, and copying the SqlLite binaries to C:\Windows\System32 but to no avail.

Finally solved it by copying the binaries to my Ruby bin directory (C:\Ruby192\bin), based on advice from this post: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/216270#977959.