# after running bundle install with rubymine still gems are missing

Tags: ruby, rubymine

I started a new rails application project with rubymine.
After that Rubymine ran a bundle install.

project did not succeed in running
on one project - with no mysql definition the error is
gemnotfound - could not find gem sqlite

on one project - with mysql definition the error is
gemnotfound - could not find gem mysql2

Does someone have an idea what are those ? 
shouldnt bundle install brought me those? 
How can I start a simple rails project using rubymine? 
Is there a good tutorial with all these issues ? 
Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RubyMine may not be able to install these gems automatically as they depend on native libraries that may not be available on your system. You also need [DevKit](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit) installed and working in order to install native extensions.

I suggest you to read related posts:

- [Cannot install mysql2 gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841406/cannot-install-mysql2-gem)
- [Installing SQLite 3.6 On Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734629/installing-sqlite-3-6-on-windows-7)

You can also use `sqlite-ruby` instead, as for the above gems you need `sqlite3.dll` and `libmysql.dll` in `PATH`.

Google is your friend, it's not that hard to find various installation guides.